# Rails 4 - rendering views is slow due associations

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this query:

```
  @companies = Company.includes(:car, :member).where('companies.status != 3 AND companies.status != 4 AND companies.status != 5').order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
```

Views:
`all_companies.html.erb`:

```
  <div id="cars_list">
    <%= render :partial => 'companies_list', locals: { companies: @companies } %>
  </div>
```

`_companies_list.html.erb`:

```
<div class="tr">
  <span class="td">ID</span>
  <span class="td">Registration</span>
  ...
</div>
<% companies.each do |company| %>
  <%= form_tag edit_inline_company_path(:id => company.id), :method => "post", :id => "id#{company.id}", :remote => true do %>
    <%= render :partial => 'edit_inline_company', locals: { company: company } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

`_edit_inline_company.html.erb`:

```
<span class="td">
  <span class="td">
    <%= company.id %>     
  </span>
  <span class="td">
    <%= company.location %>     
  </span>
  <span class="td">
    <%= company.registered_at %>     
  </span>
  ...
  <span class="td">
    <%= company.member.full_name %>     
  </span>
  <span class="td">
    <%= company.car.code %>     
  </span>
  <span class="td">
    <%= company.car.driver %>     
  </span>
  ...
</span>
```

Problem - the view takes 1800ms to render (there's only about 40-50 items to display).

I added to the query `.includes(:car, :member)` to avoid the N+1 problem (but in fact, it didn't affect the speed at all).

After some debugging, I tried to to remove from `_edit_inline_company.html.erb` the items that are associated with different models these ones:

```
  <span class="td">
    <%= company.member.full_name %>     
  </span>
  <span class="td">
    <%= company.car.code %>     
  </span>
  <span class="td">
    <%= company.car.driver %>     
  </span>
```

And the time needed to render the data dropped on approx. 700ms, however, I need these fields as well in the output.

How to optimize it? What might have I overlooked?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

I tried to add indexes as @brenzy suggested, like this:

```
add_index :companies, :car_id, :name => 'car_id_ix'
add_index :companies, :member_id, :name => 'memberr_id_ix'
```

+ `rake db:migrate`, but the loading times stay the same, no speeding up here.

Comment: Try to remove all partials from your code and check Views render time once again. Also could you give us Views | ActiveRecord times that displays under each request?

Answer (score 0):

Try indexing your associations.  Here is a link that may be helpful: https://tomafro.net/2009/08/using-indexes-in-rails-index-your-associations

Comment: Thank you @brenzy, I tried it, but it seems that it didn't affect the performance.

Comment: @user984621 - You are searching on companies.status, so I would try indexing that as well...